# Some equivalence relation from flipping binary trees

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory, trees, equivalence-relations

I know almost nothing in combinatorics, so this question might be very easy, or well-known.

Fix a number $n$. We will consider rooted planar binary trees with $n$ leaves. We will distinguish between the root (some fixed vertex of valency $1$), leaves (vertices of valency $1$ that are not the root) and internal vertices (vertices of valency $3$).

On these trees we can define the following operations. For any internal vertex $v$ of a tree $T$ we can flip the two branches growing up from $v$ as it is shown on the picture:
[image]

Then we say two trees $T_1$ and $T_2$ are equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by some combination of the operations described above.

**So my question is:** how can we describe the set of equivalences classes? I would be happy with the answer of the type: we can (easily) encode trees into some "data", and then each equivalence class is represented by the "data" that satisfies some conditions. Here "data" is maybe a sequence of numbers, or something else (I don't know combinatorics, so I don't know what are the efficient tools to deal with this kind of problem).

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This equivalence relation also goes by 'rooted isomorphic' and you're after the isomorphism classes of rooted trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a canonical rooted tree representation. One such representation can be given as follows (Aho, Hopcroft, Ullman):

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node Tree Tree

canonical_name Leaf = "ab"
canonical_name (Node left_subtree right_subtree) = 
  let left_name = canonical_name left_subtree in
  let right_name = canonical_name right_subtree in
  if left_name < right_name then "a" + left_name + right_name + "b"
  else "a" + right_name + left_name + "b"
```

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 3):

To help you learn more about this class of trees note that they have the ordinary generating function $T(z)$ with the functional equation (where $[z^n] T(z)$ counts the equivalence classes on $n$ nodes) 
$$T(z) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} z T(z)^2 + \frac{1}{2} z T(z^2).$$
by the Polya enumeration theorem applied to $D_2,$ whose cycle index is $\frac{1}{2}(q_1^2+q_2).$

Enter this equation into your favorite CAS to obtain the following sequence:
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 23, 46, 98, 207, 451, 983, 2179, 4850, 10905, \ldots$$

This is enough data to consult the OEIS, where we find that these are the so-called    [Wedderburn-Etherington numbers](http://oeis.org/A001190).

Knowing that, we can in turn consult the [MathWorld entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeaklyBinaryTree.html), which has some nice pictures. Enjoy!

The Maple code for the initial segment of the functional equation is this:

```
T_approx := q -> add(a[k]*z^k, k=0..q);

r := 1 + 1/2*z*T_approx(15)^2 + 1/2*z*subs(z=z^2, T_approx(15));
r_ex := expand(r):
eqs := {seq(coeff(r_ex, z, k) = a[k], k=0..15)}:

solve(%);
subs(%, [seq(a[k], k=0..15)]);
```

**Addendum 2015-02-16.** A much more efficient computation is given by the recurrence relation $$t_n = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} t_q t_{n-1-q} 
+ [[n-1\equiv 0\bmod 2]]\frac{1}{2} t_{(n-1)/2}$$
where we have used the Iverson bracket and $t_0 = 1.$